# In NIST modulus and key size recommendations is `group` equivalent to modulus and `key` equivalent to exponent?

Tags: public-key, diffie-hellman, keys, discrete-logarithm

Looking at the following [NIST](https://www.keylength.com/en/4/) recommendations for a discrete logarithm, for 2016-2030 and beyond they list 3072-bit number for the `group` and 256-bit for the `key`.

If using Diffie-Hellman, does `group` equal the recommended size of the prime modulus and `key` equal the recommended size of the private key exponent?

Comment: See also from SecuritySO; [Is there a key length definition for DH or DHE?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42558/is-there-a-key-length-definition-for-dh-or-dhe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, when using cryptosystems based on the difficulty of the Discrete Logarithm in $\Bbb Z_p^*$ or a subgroup thereof, a key size recommendation of a 3072-bit *group* means that the modulus $p$ is 3072-bit, and a 256-bit *key* implies that a private exponent (a key) is 256-bit.

In some (as far as I know: all) NIST contexts, a 256-bit *key* additionally implies that the order of the public generator $g$ is a 256-bit prime $q$, and (thus) that $p-1$ has that 256-bit prime factor $q$, and public keys belong to a subgroup of $\Bbb Z_p^*$ having order $q$. The generation of $p$ and $q$ is described in [FIPS 186-4 appendix A](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/fips/nist.fips.186-4.pdf#page=40) (Dave Thompson's [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/148635?noredirect=1) explains that's for various sizes including 3072/256).

In all contexts, a private exponent should be at least twice as wide as the security level in bits, which guards against [Baby-step giant-step](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby-step_giant-step) and [Pollard's rho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm). It is good and customary that $p-1$ has a large prime factor $q$, and that the order of the generator $g$ is a multiple of that $q$. That $q$ should be at least twice as wide as the security level in bits, which guards against [Pohlig-Hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pohlig%E2%80%93Hellman_algorithm).

The width of $p$ is dictated by resistance to a Discrete-Log extension of [GNFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve), which is why recommendations for this parameters match those for RSA public moduli.

In Diffie-Hellman, it can (but need not) be chosen $p$ such that $q=(p-1)/2$ is prime, and thus $g$ of order $(p-1)/2$ or $p-1$, even when the key is narrower.

Comment: The 'backward compatibility' verification in 186-4 A.1.1.1, for parameters generated per now-obsoleted 186-2, is only 1024/160, but the _current_ procedures in A.1.1.2-3 and A.1.2.1-2 use the sizes defined in 4.2 (referenced by A.1) which are 1024/160 2048/224 2048/256 3072/256 constrained by SP800-57 whose rev3 in 2012 prohibited signing with 1024/160 (80-strength) after 2013, and the next two (112-strength) after 2030. Cf https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/19005/why-does-fips-186-4-require-specific-sizes-for-keys